# OSError when trying to run XGBoost on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I installed xgboost through pip and am trying to run it on Jupyter Notebook.
However, when running

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
```

on a Python 3 jupyter notebook, I get the following error:

```
OSError: /home/martin/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libgomp.so.1: version GOMP_4.0' not found (required by /home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so)
```

What do I do?

Comment: update: I got some help from https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1786

Comment: problem is, now I'm getting the following error:
OSError: /home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so)

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Again, found a solution at https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1786

In order to get GOMP_4.0 to work, follow these steps:

1) enter the following on a terminal (replace path with your own)

```
strings /home/martin/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libgomp.so.1 |grep GOMP
```

You will get a list, GOMP_4.0 will most likely not be there (if it is I don't think this will work because that's not the problem)

2) Enter

```
sudo find / -name libgomp.so.1*
```

You will get a list of addresses. Repeat step 1 (`strings <path> |grep GOMP`) with each of those until you find one that includes GOMP_40 (in my case, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1`)

3) Now enter the following, first with your original path, and then with the one that contains GOMP_4.0

```
sudo rm -rf <path in anaconda>
sudo ln -s <path with GOMP_4.0> <path in anaconda>
```

for example:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/martin/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libgomp.so.1
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 /home/martin/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libgomp.so.1
```

This should solve the issue. After this, though, I got a similar error:

OSError: /home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/backe‌​nd/cython/../../../.‌​./.././libstdc++.so.‌​6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/martin/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xgboost/.‌​/lib/libxgboost.so)

I solved this the same way, except this time, use `|grep GLIBCXX` in step 1), `sudo find / -name libgomp.so.1*` in step 2), and this time look for GLIBCXX_3.4.20.